# CentOS/SwarmPit/Docker/Sonarqube error on startup: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]

Tags: docker, sonarqube, docker-swarm

I have a setup as follows:

- Docker host: CentOS
- Docker node: CentOS
- Orchestration: Swarmpit

When I try to start up my Sonarqube container, I get the error

> ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed. You must address the points described in the following [1] lines before starting Elasticsearch.
> bootstrap check failure [1] of [1]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]

What I have tried:
On the host:

- sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
- sysctl -p
- sysctl --system
- docker restart (swarmpit app container id)

I see the task retry and the same error comes up. On a whim, I checked the node OS where the docker service was deployed to and that still has the 65530 value. Does anyone know if this value needs to be changed on all the nodes? I assume so, but there's no mention anywhere I have found on the interwebs.

Appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like changing the value on the swarm nodes is the way to go. Same instructions as fixing the issue on a single container host, but on each node. #GrayHairMinimized